# ElasticSearch + Go: Index failures (No feature for name)

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get ElasticSearch to index content for my autocomplete service, using Completion Suggesters in v1.4x. I was following advice from [ElasticSearch - You Complete Me](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/you-complete-me/) and am using the Go Client [olivere/elastic](https://github.com/olivere/elastic).

My index method looks a bit like this:

```
func IndexVehicle(client *elastic.Client, vehicle Vehicle) (bool, error) {
    // See if it exists already
    fetch, err := client.Get().
        Index(vehicleIndex).
        Type("vehicle").
        Id(vehicle.Id).
        Do()
    if err != nil || fetch.Found {
        return false, err
    }

    vehicleName := fmt.Sprintf("%s %s (%s) %s", vehicle.Make, vehicle.Model, vehicle.Model_year, vehicle.Primary_fuel)

    suggest := elastic.NewSuggestField()
    suggest.Input(vehicle.Make, vehicle.Model, vehicle.Primary_fuel, vehicle.Model_year).
        Output(vehicleName).
        Payload(vehicle)

    // Go forth and save
    put, err := client.Index().
        Index(vehicleIndex).
        Type("vehicle").
        Id(vehicle.Id).
        Debug(true).Pretty(true).
        BodyJson(indexBody{Name: vehicleName, Suggest: suggest}).
        Do()
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    return put.Created, nil
}
```

Now what is weird, is that in some of my tests this method works fine and items will be indexed. In other tests after wiping and rebuilding the index the tests will fail:

Earlier tests look like this in the debug:

```
2014/12/15 14:11:37 PUT /vehicle/vehicle/369f96459b340507c4688740da3bfe1a?pretty=true HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
User-Agent: elastic/1.3.1 (darwin-amd64)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"name":"American Motors Corporation Eagle 4WD (1986) regular","suggest":{"input":["American Motors Corporation","Eagle 4WD","regular","1986"],"output":"American Motors Corporation Eagle 4WD (1986) regular","payload":{"make":"American Motors Corporation","model_year":"1986","model":"Eagle 4WD","primary_fuel":"regular","vehicle_class":"Special Purpose Vehicle 4WD","transmission":"Automatic 3-spd","displacement":"4.2","drive":"4-Wheel or All-Wheel Drive","city_mpg":"15.0","highway_mpg":"19.0","comb_mpg":"17.0"}}}

2014/12/15 14:11:37 HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Length: 134
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "_index" : "vehicle",
  "_type" : "vehicle",
  "_id" : "369f96459b340507c4688740da3bfe1a",
  "_version" : 1,
  "created" : true
}
```

But in later tests, doing this same thing leads to errors. The `err` returned from `IndexVehicle()` in later tests is:

```
E
Errors:

  * /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/ride/autocomplete/vehicle_test.go 
  Line 79: - elastic: Error 400: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No feature for name [vehicle]] 
  goroutine 245 [running]:
  github.com/ride/autocomplete.func·033()
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/ride/autocomplete/vehicle_test.go:79 +0x249
  github.com/ride/autocomplete.useIndex(0x499e98)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/ride/autocomplete/test_helper.go:18 +0x55
  github.com/ride/autocomplete.func·034()
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/ride/autocomplete/vehicle_test.go:96 +0x2a
  github.com/jtolds/gls._m(0x0, 0xc2080ae9e0)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/jtolds/gls/stack_tags.go:70 +0x32
  github.com/jtolds/gls.markS(0x0, 0xc2080ae9e0)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/jtolds/gls/stack_tags.go:21 +0x32
  github.com/jtolds/gls.addStackTag(0x0, 0xc2080ae9e0)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/jtolds/gls/stack_tags.go:18 +0x3e
  github.com/jtolds/gls.(*ContextManager).SetValues(0xc20801e080, 0xc2080b31d0, 0xc2080ae9e0)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/jtolds/gls/context.go:98 +0x503
  github.com/ride/autocomplete.TestSearchForVehicles(0xc20806a480)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/ride/autocomplete/vehicle_test.go:97 +0x243
  testing.tRunner(0xc20806a480, 0x5be890)
    /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:447 +0xbf
  created by testing.RunTests
    /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:555 +0xa8b

  goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
  testing.RunTests(0x49a078, 0x5be800, 0x7, 0x7, 0x67c001)
    /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:556 +0xad6
  testing.(*M).Run(0xc2080463c0, 0x5c9b20)
    /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:485 +0x6c
  main.main()
    github.com/ride/autocomplete/_test/_testmain.go:64 +0x1d5

  goroutine 208 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208106d40)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 248 [runnable]:
  net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc20802e4d0)
    /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:928 +0x9ce
  created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:660 +0xc9f

  goroutine 98 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208033e00)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
  runtime.goexit()
    /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

  goroutine 44 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc2080332c0)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 249 [select]:
  net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc20802e4d0)
    /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:945 +0x41d
  created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:661 +0xcbc

  goroutine 54 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208032f80)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 76 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208032e00)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 250 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208106c40)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 120 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208106b00)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 142 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208106e00)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 164 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208106b80)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 186 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208106d00)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e

  goroutine 230 [chan receive]:
  github.com/olivere/elastic.(*Client).pinger(0xc208106dc0)
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:79 +0x6b
  created by github.com/olivere/elastic.NewClient
    /Users/phil/go/src/github.com/olivere/elastic/client.go:60 +0x26e
```

Possibly the more important part of that backtrace is this:

> Error 400: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No feature for name [vehicle]]

So, not sure what the heck is going wrong here. I have a 1 second timeout on the index, because this client doesn't support "wait for green" logic [yet].

```
func ResetVehicleIndex(client *elastic.Client) (err error) {

    if _, err = client.DeleteIndex(vehicleIndex).Do(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if _, err = EnsureVehicleIndex(client); err != nil {
        return
    }

    // TODO: This is awful. Switch to "wait for green" when elastic client supports it
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

    return nil
}
```

This has worked for most other tests, as elasticsearch seems to get ready in a second or so, but these tests are consistently erroring regardless of the wait time in that bit of code.

Any ideas? I might need to edit the question to add more code or better explanations, but I'll reply super quickly to any questions especially if you ping me on Twitter [@philsturgeon](http://twitter.com/philsturgeon). I'm really stuck on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That exception is [only triggered in one place](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/1.4/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/get/GetIndexRequest.java#L79-L85), which is during a Get Index API call.  Which means your vehicle ID must be null here:

```
fetch, err := client.Get().
        Index(vehicleIndex).
        Type("vehicle").
        Id(vehicle.Id).       //<-- this
        Do()
```

You are trying to do a Get Document API, which follows the format of `GET /{index}/{type}/{id}`.  However, your client doesn't make a distinction between Get Document and Get Index API calls...and it doesn't validate that your parameters are non-null.

So if a null `vehicle.Id` is passed to the Get method, your final URL will actually be `GET /{index}/{type}/`

From Elasticsearch's point of view, this is no longer a Get Document API call...it's actually a Get Index call, which has the following format:  `GET /{index}/{feature}`.  Feature can be one of: `_settings`, `_mappings`, `_aliases` or `_warmers`.

Because `vehicle` is not one of those features, ES is throwing an exception and spewing.  You can verify this from the console:

`curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/vehicle/`

Comment: Perfection! Yeah this was some shitty code where one method was setting the ID and another method was not. I'm changing things to make a `GetId()` method, so it will always exist. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help, glad it was an easy fix! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: I had the same error when I initialized my request method with "post" instead of "POST"

like so:

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("post", url, query)
// returns: Error 400: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No feature for name [_bulk]]
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, query)
// works just fine
```